# Use a contract at a specific address

Tags: solidity, truffle

In migration file i'm deploying one contract and for that contract i'm passing another contract's address as a constructor parameter

```
var jbkContract = artifacts.require("./JBK.sol");
var payBContract = artifacts.require("./payback.sol");
var contract_address = '0xB525F2F0046fA37f21EaF1F0619B3de7c1094324';
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  let ins = await jbkContract.at(contract_address);
  await deployer.deploy(payBContract,ins,{"from":"0x69A9CAEc73e4378801266dFc796d92aFC98013f6"});
};
```

For this i'm getting this error

```
"payback" -- invalid address (arg="_jbkContract", coderType="address", value="[object Object]").
```

Earlier i was deploying JBKContract and then using that address i was deploying the payback contract and that was working fine.

```
var jbkContract = artifacts.require("./JBK.sol");
var payBContract = artifacts.require("./payback.sol");
module.exports = async function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(jbkContract,1000000,"JBK","JBK",{"from":"0x69A9CAEc73e4374401266dFc796d92aFC98013f6"}).then(
    function() {
      return deployer.deploy(payBContract,jbkContract.address,{"from":"0x69A9CAEc73e4374401266dFc796d92aFC98013f6"});
    }
  )
};
```

But i don't want to deploy JBK contract only once and use that contract's address to deploy Payback everytime.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 issues here.

1.`0xB525F2F0046fA37f21EaF1F0619B3de7c1094324` is not an address with valid `checksum`. Address with valid `checksum` is `0xB525f2f0046Fa37F21Eaf1F0619b3DE7C1094324`. This might not be a problem in `Truffle` though.

2.In the first chunk of code in this line

```
await deployer.deploy(payBContract, ins, {"from":"0x69A9CAEc73e4378801266dFc796d92aFC98013f6"});
```

you are passing the `contract instance` as a parameter instead of `contract address`. Correct code might be

```
await deployer.deploy(payBContract, ins.address, {"from":"0x69A9CAEc73e4378801266dFc796d92aFC98013f6"});
```